# Setting Script Property using it in "if" in Google

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that is supposed to mail a chart URL when a metric falls out of X range and Only if someone has entered a new metric.  It's mailing everytime I run the script so I know the setProperty is not working and the "if" statement isn't working because it's only supposed to mail if X is TRUE.

The sheet...  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai_2YLvaQba0dHN1dWFpY0ZSbGpudWF4cTJYNlFwNHc&usp=sharing

My code...

```
function myAverages() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var value = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("P2").getValue().toString();
  var outside = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("S2").getValue().toString;
  var mailed = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("T2").getValue().toString();
  var stemiAverage = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("R2").getValue().toString();
  var stemiChart = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("U2").getValue().toString();
  var last = ScriptProperties.getProperty('last');

  //if "value" is not equal to ScriptProperty "last" AND "outside" is TRUE, then mail   
  if(value =! last, outside = "TRUE")

  {
   MailApp.sendEmail("dave@mydomain.com", "Metric Warning",
    "Yearly STEMI Average has fallen below 65%, it is now: " + stemiAverage + "%" +
    "\n\nTo see the current trending chart " + stemiChart + "\n\n The sheet that    calculated this is here " + ss.getUrl());
   ScriptProperties.setProperty('last','value');
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can lend.  I'm teaching myself this stuff and feel very much like a newby.  I've tried a hundred or more combinations to the script before posting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a complement to Phil's answer and following your comment, there is another error in your script :

```
   ScriptProperties.setProperty("last","value");
```

should be

```
   ScriptProperties.setProperty({'last':value},true);
```

The `true` parameter is optional, see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptproperties?hl=en#setProperties) on ScriptProperties, it gives you the possibility to delete all other keys.

So you're complete function with corrections would be :

```
function myAverages(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var value = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("P2").getValue().toString();
  Logger.log('value = '+value)    
      var outside = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("S2").getValue().toString();
  Logger.log('outside='+outside)
      var mailed = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("T2").getValue().toString();
  Logger.log('mailed = '+mailed)    
      var stemiAverage = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("R2").getValue().toString();
      var stemiChart = ss.getSheetByName("EmailServices").getRange("U2").getValue().toString();
      var last = ScriptProperties.getProperty('last');
  Logger.log('last='+last)    
       if(value != last && outside == "true"){
          MailApp.sendEmail("me@mydomain.com", "Metric Warning",
          "Yearly STEMI Average has fallen below 65%, it is now: " + stemiAverage + "%" +
          "\n\nTo see the current trending chart " + stemiChart + "\n\n The sheet that    calculated this is here " + ss.getUrl());
          ScriptProperties.setProperty({'last':value});
  Logger.log('mail sent')
         }
    }
```

Comment: Serge ultimately helped me fix the code.  I appreciate all the help and comments.  I am just learning about this stuff and Serge showed me how to use the logger as well which we left in the solution above.  Very cool stuff.  Thanks again Serge

Comment: you're welcome, glad it helped and good luck in your GAS journey ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AND operator: `&&`.

And also, checking for equality requires 2 equals signs: `==`.

So be sure you try this:

```
if (value!=last && outside=="TRUE") {
```

Comment: I can seem to get the ScriptProperties to work by using 'last' instead of "last". but if I put the & or && symbols in my if statement I get an error Invalid assignment left-hand side. (line 1).  I am going to correct the ScriptProperties in the above code, but I still have to work out the AND outside = "TRUE".

Comment: No, the ScriptProperties by itself is not working either.  :(